# PHP & Mysqli - Multiple querys in one?

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to get the ID (a column) from the last row inserted, in a table. I'm wondering if there's any way to somehow embed that in another query, to avoid having two different querys? It seems much simpler, and i believe i've seen it somewhere before.

Something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO a_table (x, y) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM another_table ORDER BY id DESC), 'y...')";
```

Any ideas how to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get the newest record created by your script, you should never do it this way in the first place. What if another instance of your script created a record at the same time?

mySQL's [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en//information-functions.html) will return the last ID created *over this specific connection.* However, you must call it immediately after your insert statement.

If getting the highest ID is literally what you want, GSto's answer will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO a_table (x, y) VALUES (SELECT max(id), 'y...' FROM another_table);
```

Comment: He is on mysqli, where there doesn't seem to be such a function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL has an INSERT .. SELECT statement:

example:

INSERT INTO a_table (x,y) SELECT id,'y' FROM another_table ORDER BY id DESC

although keep in mind, unless you have an auto_incrementing ID field, the order by clause is pointless here.

Comment: I'll look into that. And yes, i've set the ID field to auto increment. Otherwise i wouldn't see the point of an ID? I mean, an ID should be unique and you shouldn't have to check for the latest ID before you insert a new row, that's just... pointless. Thanks!

Comment: How would that work if i'm binding parameters? Here's my original insert code: http://codepad.org/Yvu9SoVp , how would i do to select the ID from another table and insert it as example_id?

Comment: Yes, i know, but i need to get the ID from another table. Could someone give me an example (take a look at this codepad.org/Yvu9SoVp) on how to do it? It'd be really appreciated.

Comment: @Albert there are other ways to have unique ids, such as MD5 hashes, or some kind of combined primary key.

Comment: @GSto, yeah, but the whole point with IDs is still to be able to target an row with an unique ID. I'm sure there are many ways of creating unique IDs, but in this case (and most, i believe), an auto incrementing field seems to be the best option. Any ideas on how to implement this into my code snippet?

Comment: Actually, an even better alternative in this case would be to fetch an ID while i'm inserting a row. Like, i insert a row with an auto incrementing ID, and then the ID is fetched in the same query at the same time? Maybe i can use UNION for that, i'll google that, any tips?